# How to specify dependency for @Test in two different classes using TestNg?

Tags: java, testng

I want to run class2 method2 after class1 method1.
How to specify dependency for the above scenario?
I tried with dependOnGroups and dependOnMethods but it is not working. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make you of `groups` and `beforeGroups`. Consider the following example:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ClassA {


    @Test(groups = {"group-A"})
    public void classAmethodA(){
        System.out.println("This is method A of class A");
    }


    @Test(groups = {"group-B"})
    public void classAmethodB(){
        System.out.println("This is method B of class A");
    }
}


public class ClassB {

    @Test()
    @BeforeGroups(groups = "group-B")
    public void classBmethodA(){
        System.out.println("This is method A of class B");
    }

    public void classBmethodB(){
        System.out.println("This is method B of class B");
    }
}
```

Here `classAmethodB()` is a part of "group-B" so, whenever you run the test method, TestNG will look for `@BeforeGroups` with "group-B" and run it before running the test. Hence the running order will be
`classBmethodA()` -> `classAmethodB()`

Other way to do this is calling the method `classBmethodA()` inside `classAmethodB()`, something like below:

```
public void classAmethodB(){
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.classBmethodA();
        System.out.println("This is method B of class A");
}
```